# Ngx Admin takes 10 seconds to load, how to improve speed?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ngx-charts

So my NGX Admin installation takes 10 seconds to load while the demo and especially documentation instance located here loads at ultra speed of 2 seconds! https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/

How did they make it so fast 1-2 seconds while for me it takes 10 seconds to load a ngx-admin instance? Please help me improve speed

Answer (score 3):

It is fast because it's running production version. You can try to build it first,

```
npm build:prod
```

Then, serve the bundled app, in the folder dist.